# Examples of solutions of 2D Poisson Equation with homogeneous boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, finite-element-method

I'm looking for analytic solutions of Poisson type equations
$$ \Delta u(x,y) = f(x,y), \quad u_{| \Omega} = 0 $$
where $ \Omega = [0,1] \times [0,1] $ with different $f$.

The purpose is to test the goodness of the FEM method I implemented with some dummy problems.

Comment: There don't exist particularly many interesting solutions expressible in "elementary functions". It is one of the reasons why so many numerical methods were developed for this purpose in the first place.

Comment: Is the Poisson equation not $\Delta u(x,y)=f(x,y)$ ?  If you assume separate variables you can probably find some closed form solutions.

Comment: As @KurtG. made me notice, it's actually $\Delta u = f$. I'll edit the question.

Comment: If you just want to come up with examples why not just pick some $u$ then calculate $f$? E.g. one could be $u(x,y)=xy(1-x)(1-y)$ then let $f:= \Delta u$

Comment: As an add-on to @JackT proposition, note that to test your FEM solver, if you consider his example with P2 finite elements, the error should vanish at machine precision for any mesh size, since $u$ is in the discrete space, whereas if you take P1 element it should converge to zero as the grid step size goes to zero at the order predicted by the theory (which depends on the chosen norm).